# Pythonic: code name conflicting with built-in

Tags: package, python, built-in

I'm currently creating a code named "SET". The code's name is an acronym, which has been defined for many (non programming) reasons, and therefore cannot be changed.

**Problem:** The easiest, and I believe the less painful way for the end-user to use my code would be naming the package "set".
But of course this is a problem since this conflicts with the built-in ***set*** function.

**Question:** What are the possible solutions? Some may be (there is probably more):

1. change the package name (eg. setb).

   ```
   import setb
   ```

   I would really really prefer not to, because then it will be different from the real name
2. make the package's name upper-case (SET)

   ```
   import SET
   ```

   It would be a straight forward solution, but I'm wondering: is this a pythonic proper naming for a package? Also, I find this a bit painful since all modules defined in the code will have something like "import SET.x.y..." (ie. upper-case, written a lot of times). But this is not a really big deal if this is a pythonic way.
3. keep the name "set"

   ```
   import set
   ```

   Well this is obviously not fine. But it would be a problem only if the user is using "import set", would not it be? This should not happen in "normal usage conditions", since the code will provides some scripts to use it, rather use it as a standard python module. But we never know, and it could be imported as it, and there may be even some problems I'm not seeing (with the built-in set).

I'm considering the solution 2., but I'm really not sure. Maybe this is not proper, or maybe you guys have a better solution.

PS: I've found some similar topics on the web and on stackoverflow, but it usually deals with names inside a script or module inside a package. The problem here is really related to the code's name (which is meaningful only written this way), and therefore related to the proper naming of the package's name.

---

EDIT

**Selected solution:** I've choosen to use "SET" as the package name. Although many good suggestions have been proposed here: pyset, semt, setool... or the more explicit "starexoplanettool" (expliciting the acronym). Thanks to you all.

EDIT #2

I like the "funny" solution of having a package named S, and a subpackage, E... to get finally:

```
    import S.E.T
```

Thanks Don Question.

Comment: Tough one. If it's an acronym, try writing out the last part of it. You can also rename it to `pyset`. If you can't possibly change it to something longer and more verbose, I'd stick with the uppercase variant.

Comment: @NiklasB. Nice suggestion, thanks. It could in fact be a solution if no better one could be found and the upper-case one is not pythonic.

Comment: May I ask what the full name is? :)

Comment: Sure: Star and Exoplanet modelling Tool :)

Comment: In that case the acronym really is a bad choice :D You could have used `SEXOMOD` or something ;) Well, I'd use `setool` for that, although that might be ambigious as well. *EDIT*: Actually I think `import stexo` would be quite nice :)

Comment: Why not use ``semt`` or ``setool``?

Comment: @NiklasB. Well, SEXOMOD is not the best name to me :) I'd rather stick with something close to the code name (people that will use it, won't really know the meaning of it, but will rather use the acronym, therefore it explains a bit the (bad) choice of name SET)

Comment: `semt`.  for heavens sake, don't use `set`

Comment: just don't call it `sextool` or `sexmodtool`

Comment: I have to agree that SET is a poor choice of acronym. Is the package you're naming specifically a "tool"? How? If not, I would call it `sem` (Star and Exoplanet Modelling). `from sem import ExoplanetTool`.

Comment: @jozzas Yeah the fact SET is a poor acronym has been "set" :) But this cannot change, and it is in fact a bunch of tools to do modelling. Here "tool" refers to the fact that it actually rely on pre-computed models. Without this keyword, people (at least the ones who'll use it) would probably understand it as a code that really make a modelling (which is different and much much longer and cannot do what my code will).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this a pythonic proper naming for a package?

Under the circumstances, it doesn't matter.

Leading upper case is rare (ConfigParser, HTMLParser).  Camel-case is rare (cStringIO).
But that doesn't make all upper-case wrong.

It just means you should pick a better acronym next time.

"set" is the English word with the largest number of definitions.  It is the **single** poorest choice of acronym possible.

The point is not to conform to a community "standard" of more-or-less acceptable behavior.

The point is to write something that works.

> (ie. upper-case, written a lot of times).

Hardly a concern.  People actually run software more often than they write it.

People read  and tweak more often than writing, also.

If you're worried about misspelling, there's copy and paste.

Also, even a cheap IDE like Komodo Edit can figure out how to code-complete an installed module with a long name.

Comment: So you are saying don't bother seeking a better solution? Python has a set of guidelines for a reason. They help programmers, which is a good thing. Yes, it's not the end of the world (which is why they are guidelines, not rules), but why not try?

Comment: They're guidelines.  Not laws.  The acronym SET is the worst possible acronym, since it's an English word with the largest number of meanings.  What "better solution" are you suggesting?

Comment: @S.Lott: There are some. Many packages choose just to put `py` in front of there name or write out parts of the acronym.

Comment: See my answer. I suggest giving it a full name, spelling out the acronym. This gives it a more unique and clear name, and in the case the user really needs a shorter name, Python has the ``as`` keyword there to help.

Comment: @S.Lott. Thanks for your answer. Indeed, I do agree that choosing an acronym with so many meanings was not the best thing ever, but it was choosen for simplicity, and because it was not used (or is meaningless) to the people that will use the code.

Comment: @mhavel: Simplicity in this specific case may not be a virtue.  Acronyms are not always good thing.  The TLA is usually a mistake.  The TLA "SET" is doubly so.

Comment: @S.Lott Yes, I do agree that "simplicity" may sometimes be not a good choice, but in this case, the name was voted (with many people)... and by experience, I know that the people who will use my code will most likely prefer a short, easy-to-remember name. Anyway, your answer was helpful to me, thanks

Answer (score 6):

Why not spell out the meaning behind the acronym, and if the user is desperate for a shorter name, they can do `import someetymologyterm as SET` or whatever they prefer. Python gives them the choice, so it's not the end of the world either way.

Comment: `import starandexpoplanetmodellingtool as s`

Comment: Heh, the whole name wasn't given when I suggested this. In this case, simply spelling out part of it would probably best, maybe ``setool`` for example, given the very long name.

Comment: But my concern with such a solution (thanks for giving it btw.) was to use inside the code a lot of "import someetymologyterm". But as S. Lott pointed out, it may not be even a concern after all :)

Comment: @Lattyware Sorry, I'm reading and answering much slower than you guys here are helping me :)

Answer (score 3):

If you have to choose such a misfortunate name, you could make the pain in the ass an ironic anathema! Just create a main-package "S" with a subpackage "E" and therein a subpackage "T".
Then you could do an:

```
import S.E.T
```

or

```
from s.e.t import xyz
```

or

```
import s.e.t as set_
```

you could even do some vodoo in the `__init__.py` file of the main-pacakge ;-)

Just my 2 cents!

Comment: ahah, nice one. It is a funny way to do this :) I'll have to think about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not getting it but this looks simply like a namespace problem.

Here is one way out. Prepend the path to the set.py onto the sys.path Before the import takes place. You can wrap this in a function which backs out the change after the import.

I'm in train so can't test this but that is what I would try.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the code is working just fine, it is just a matter of coding style. By creating a package named "set", it may in some cases redefines the built-in python function with the same name. Also, I actually don't have any file called "set.py", it is just the package name. But thanks for your contribution I appreciate :)